# How to determine radius of curvature of cycloid using centripetal acceleration?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics

Whenever it comes to radius of curvature of complex curves like cycloid, we all take the help of calculus. But I am still in high school and not that competent with calculus, so please do not answer using calculus.

Another interesting resource which I found was this: www.jstor.org/stable/2967957.
But this makes use of geometry.

I found a problem while doing my physics(rotation) homework which asked to calculate radius of curvature of the path traced by a point on the circumference of a disc rotating without slipping on a surface. I think that this must be somehow related to the chapter.

So can someone tell how to do it using some rotation concepts?

Answer (score 3):

**Hints**

---

[image]

---

**A.  Looking at Figure 01**

1. *A cycloid is a curve traced by a point $\:\mathrm P\:$ on the rim of a circular wheel as the wheel rolls along a straight line without slipping*.(Wikipedia)
2. *A brachistochrone curve<sup>$\rm 1$</sup> or curve of fastest descent, is the one lying on plane between a point $\:\mathrm A\:$ and a lower point $\:\mathrm F$, where $\:\mathrm F\:$ is not directly below A, on which a bead $\:\mathrm P\:$ slides frictionlessly under the influence of a uniform gravitational $\:\mathbf{g}\:$ field in the shortest time*.(Wikipedia)

To determine the radius of curvature $\:\rho\:$ of the cycloid using centripetal acceleration we note at first that for any curvilinear motion (not necessarily circular)

\begin{equation}
\Vert\mathbf{a}_{\textrm{n}}\Vert=\dfrac{\Vert\boldsymbol{\upsilon}\Vert^{2}}{\rho}=\dfrac{\upsilon^{2}}{\rho}
\tag{01}
\end{equation}
where $\:\mathbf{a}_{\textrm{n}}\:$ the centripetal acceleration, normal to the curve and $\:\boldsymbol{\upsilon}\:$ the velocity, tangent to the curve.

---

[image]

**B.  Looking at Figure 02**

1. From the equilibrium of the bead on the direction normal to the cycloid you could determine the magnitude $\:\Vert\mathbf{a}_{\textrm{n}}\Vert\:$ of the centripetal acceleration as function of $\:\mathrm g, \theta$
   \begin{equation}
   \Vert\mathbf{a}_{\textrm{n}}\Vert=\mathrm h(\mathrm g, \theta)
   \tag{02}
   \end{equation}
   *In this Figure it seems that the straight line normal to the cycloid at point $\:\mathrm P\:$ passes through the point $\:\mathrm M\equiv$ contact point of the wheel with the straight line on which it is rolling.* **Why???**
2. From energy conservation of the bead between the starting point $\:\mathrm A\:$ and present point $\:\mathrm P\:$ you could determine the square of the speed $\:\Vert\boldsymbol{\upsilon}\Vert^{2}\:$ as function of $\:R, \mathrm g, \theta$

\begin{equation}
\Vert\boldsymbol{\upsilon}\Vert^{2}=\mathrm f(R,\mathrm g,\theta)
\tag{03}
\end{equation}

Then from (01) you'll determine the radius of curvature $\:\rho\:$ as function of $\:R,\theta$
\begin{equation}
\rho=\dfrac{\:\:\Vert\boldsymbol{\upsilon}\Vert^{2}}{\Vert\mathbf{a}_{\textrm{n}}\Vert}=\dfrac{\upsilon^{2}}{\Vert\mathbf{a}_{\textrm{n}}\Vert}=\rho(R,\theta)
\tag{04}
\end{equation}

---

After all these : what is the geometric locus of the centers of curvature ?

[image]

The geometric locus of the centers of curvature $\:\mathrm P'\:$ of points of a cycloid $\:C\:$  is a cycloid $\:C'\:$ identical to $\:C\:$ but shifted by the vector $\:(-\pi R, -2R)\:$, see Figure 03.

The new cycloid $\:C'\:$ is the *envelope* of the family of normal to the cycloid $\:C\:$  straight lines, see Figure 04.

[image]

---

<sup>$1\:\:$
For more details on the brachistochrone and tautochrone cycloids see my answer therein :  [What is the position as a function of time for a mass falling down a cycloid curve?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/177847/what-is-the-position-as-a-function-of-time-for-a-mass-falling-down-a-cycloid-cur)</sup>

Comment: Is the property regarding the locus of centre of curvature true for any trochoid?

Comment: @Umesh Konduru : Welcome to PSE. This is a purely mathematical question.  I suggest to  post it in Mathematics Stack Exchange to have answers from experts.